# How to apply for Post-doc

Tags: postdocs

I am a last year Ph.D student and intend to apply for a postdoc call starting in September. As I have not submitted my thesis yet, is it possible to apply  earlier? And how can I ask my adviser to send recommendation letter while still I have not defended my thesis? ( I mean how can I explain my adviser this demand?)

Comment: If you were a mathematics student applying for postdoc positions in the U.S., it would not be too early to apply now; it would be too late. My department, for example,has already hired most (perhaps all) of the postdocs for positions starting in September.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying for a postdoc before defending your PhD is a very common situation which your adviser should be familiar with. Just say to your adviser that you are applying for a postdoc and that you would like him to write a letter of recommendation; there shouldn't be any more to it than that.